# DNS a vs cname records

Tags: dns, cname, a-records

Let's say my domain is xyz.com
If 
- I had an A record pointing to an IP address, say 193.10.23.1
- then I had a CNAME www points to blah.cloudfront.net

But of course blah.cloudfront.net is not pointing to 193.10.23.1, will dns look up return the A record or the CNAME record? Is there an order of precedence or whether CNAMES overrides the A record?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DNS standards does not allow having both `CNAME` and `A` record:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.6.2

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present;
> this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases cannot
> be different.

DNS provider will usually will usually prevent you from adding conflicting records:

Cloudflare:

[image]

AWS Route53:

[image]